# call search form in custom module Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, catalogsearch

I want to show mini search form when i hover on one of the main category (Men Women ... ) at red area, as marked in below image.

This menu is shown using a custom extension.
Is there any way in which i can call default search form  in that custom module.

`app/code/community/WP/CustomMenu/etc/config.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
        <default>

            <block type="custommenu/toggle"></block>
           <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
        </default>
    </layout>
```

**UPdate:**

To temporarily solve my issues I did something like below in one of the blocks files `app/code/community/WP/CustomMenu/Block`

```
    public function getSearchBlock(  ) {
      $html ='<form id="search_mini_form" class="search-form" action="http://websitename.com/catalogsearch/result/" method="get">
 <input style="padding: 2px 4px 2px 5px;" id="search" type="search" name="q" value="" class="input-text required-entry" maxlength="128" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
    <button type="submit" class="button-search-submit"></button>
</form>';
       return $html;
    }
```

and then call above function at an appropriate position.
I know above method is not suggested. 
[image: minisearch]

Answer (score 0):

In your module's local.xml add these lines of codes inside your module layout:
the path is `app\design\frontend\default\default\layout\webandpeople\custommenu.xml`

```
<block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
```

[image]

Then call it in your modules's .phtml file, path of your phtml file is `app\design\frontend\default\default\template\webandpeople\custommenu\top.phtml`
around line no 49 add this code wrapped within a parent div as like

[image]

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
```

You can change 'name' and 'as' of your block as you want, just call it with the 'as' you named.

> This is not tested as third party extension does not draw much
>   attention on stack, that's all I can try.

Comment: in `app/etc/modules/` ?

Comment: In your local.xml layout file, under your layout handle..

Comment: Path should be app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/your_xml_file.xml

Comment: I think my question is not clear .

Comment: Menu is coming through a custom module which replaced the default menu . In their phtml file if i write gethcildHtml('topsearch') nothing is shown

Comment: I just updated my answer, if it works.. I haven't tested it.